# Error while loading win32ole

Tags: ruby, watir-webdriver

I'am trying to read the data from an excel file for automating a website, using RubyMine as my editor and watir-webdriver for automating my test. while doing this I get an Error in my rubyMine editor "cannot load such file -- win32_ole (LoadError)".

```
require 'watir'
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo'
require 'win32_ole'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox

Given(/^Iam on guru99 site page$/) do
  browser.goto "http://demo.guru99.com/v4/index.php"
  xl = WIN32OLE.new('Excel.Application')
  workbook = xl.Workbooks.open("C:\\Users\TekUser\Desktop.practiceExcel.xlsx")
  wrksheet= workbook.Worksheets(1)
  wrksheet.Select

  username1= wrksheet.Range("a1").Value
  password1= wrksheet.Range("b1").Value
end

When(/^I enter Username and password in the respected field$/) do
  browser.text_field(:name, "uid").set(username1)
  browser.text_field(:name,"password").set(password1)
end

Then(/^I click on login button$/) do
  browser.button(:name,"btnLogin").click

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The library name does not have an underscore. It should be:

```
require 'win32ole'
```

Comment: Hello Justin, thank you so much for your help. It works for me now